# Demora ao inicializar o Tomcat projeto Spring MVC

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, tomcat

Possuímos uma aplicação Spring MVC versão 3.2.10 que utiliza Hibernate 3.6.10, a aplicação é desenvolvida em Java e roda na versão 1.8.0.191 utilizando Tomcat 9.0.21 e banco de dados Oracle 11g, o tempo padrão de inicialização da aplicação gira em torno de 2min (120000ms), porém sem explicação em algumas máquinas com as mesmas configurações a aplicação passou a levar 4 vezes mais tempo para startar, cerca de 470000ms, configuramos todas as opções de log no logging.properties do Tomcat para **FINE** para tentar identificar o problema mas não encontramos nada de útil, a aplicação parece estar "parando" cerca de 2min após o start do StandardWrapper conforme o log:

```html
17-Dec-2021 14:21:22.344 DETALHADO [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/academico].StandardWrapper[action-portal]] to [STARTING]
17-Dec-2021 14:21:22.345 DETALHADO [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/academico].StandardWrapper[action-portal]] to [STARTED]
17-Dec-2021 14:23:53.656 DETALHADO [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardPipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/academico]]] to [INITIALIZING]
17-Dec-2021 14:23:53.657 DETALHADO [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardPipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/academico]]] to [INITIALIZED]
```

A maioria das respostas que obtive para o problema seria alterar **securerandom.source** do jre conforme sugerido [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431922/tomcat7-starts-too-late-on-ubuntu-14-04-x64-digitalocean), porém mesmo após aplicada a configuração o problema continua a ocorrer, ao startar o Tomcat sem as aplicações o tempo de subida é rápido (20000ms).

Qualquer auxílio para identificar o motivo dessa "parada" é bem vindo.

Comment: Você já verificou os logs do Oracle? Uma possibilidade é do Tomcat estar aguardando a inicialização do DBMS ou estar aguardando a inicialização de outro software.

Comment: Onde eu poderia verificar esses logs? Nossa base de dados roda em um cluster e a aplicação se conecta a ela através do oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver